# What's a safe route to ride through Mexico by bicycle?

Tags: safety, mexico, bicycles

I am cycling from Ohio to Ushuaia, Argentina starting at the very beginning of July of this year. I am trying to find the safest cycle route through Mexico.

However, I am reluctant to bike through Baja, Mexico because it adds over a thousand extra miles to my trip, and it will require cycling through the hottest parts of the U.S. in July and August. In addition Baja has had a spike in crime in recent years, so I am unsure whether or not it is still the safest route through the country.

I am also considering cycling through the states of Nuevo León and San Luís Potosí and then over to the much safer state of Veracruz because the US State Department ranks these states as the *safest* states in Northern Mexico.

But I am fully aware that the entirety of Northern Mexico is extremely dangerous and there have been a vast number of kidnappings and homicides of tourists especially.

In sum, I am in need of advice on the safest route through Mexico via bicycle. I am amenable to taking buses, taxis and or ferries through some regions, but no planes. And I absolutely need to bike when I can.

Comment: For a different perspective on cycling safety in Mexico, see http://elpedalero.com/?p=3901

Comment: @MichaelHampton While I agree witht he broad thrust of the aqrgument, based on that data I would definitley avoid Ciudad Juárez (unless it has unusally safe roads to make up for it)

Comment: I wouldn't go to Juarez with anything less than an armored tank. But I expect you'll cross a bit further east than that.

Comment: I'll object to the "tourists especially" part. The unhappy parts of Mexico are  very significantly more miserable for Mexicans than for tourists, but bad things that happen to tourists are far more likely to make the news outside of Mexico (and sometimes inside too) than those involving only Mexicans. I'd be more afraid of Guatemala, though.

Comment: @jackskis, were you able to ride through Mexico and was it safe?